# Override controller Authorize attribute for viewresult

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

If the authorize attribute has been applied to the controller is it possible to allow unauthorized access to an action/viewresult inside that controller? 
Say for example I didn't want authorization to occur on *Test2* in the following:

```
[Authorize]
public class TestController : Controller
{

    public ViewResult Test()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ViewResult Test2()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. You will have to apply the Authorize attribute on the Test action and not on the controller. Another possibility is to put the `Test2` action on another controller which is not decorated with this attribute.

Comment: New controller it is then. Thanks Darin

Comment: You also can create an AuthorizeAnonymous attribute and use it withing Authorize Controller

Answer (score 0):

Back in MVC 3 it appears it was indeed not possible to do (as mentioned Darin Dimitrov), but if anyone using MVC 4 (and up) comes across this question, he\she should be able to use `AllowAnonymous` filter to achieve the result. So the code would become:

```
[Authorize]
public class TestController : Controller
{

    public ViewResult Test()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ViewResult Test2()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```